# Timestamp format different in date and ls -- locale problem?

Tags: timestamps, locale

In `ls -l`, file timestamps are shown as `May 12 18:19` in 24-hour format.

`date` shows `Fri May 12 06:26:44 PM UTC 2023` in 12-hour format.

Is that how it is supposed to be? Or do I have my locale setup messed-up somehow?

--

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.utf8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

No aliases.

Comment: What are your locale settings? Copy-paste the output of `locale`. Do you have any aliases for `date` or `ls`?